# How to disable unread counter/badge on Dock app icon

Tags: dock, notifications

How can I disable the unread badge and jumping for attention on an app icon in my Dock? It is an app (Line chat) which isn't in `System Preferences > Notifications`, so can't disable it from there.

Would like to disable the badge as well as the jumping for attention, as both are quite distracting.

Answer (score 2):

To force all apps to stop the dock-bouncing, it's all or nothing, but you can launch the terminal and type this command:

```
$ defaults write com.apple.dock no-bouncing -bool TRUE
$ killall Dock
```

To re-enable dock-bouncing, type `FALSE` instead of true.

To remove badge icon, go to System Preferences > Notifications and select the app. You should then see the option to disable badge icons. Note: You may have to restart the app or restart the computer (simple logout/login should do) for the changes to take effect.

If you don't see it there, then I'd try perusing the Line Chat preferences or help menu to see if they have the option of disabling it.

Comment: Thanks for this option, but I don't want it disabled for all apps. Also it's not in the app settings unfortunately, tried that one.